# Azure DevOps onPremise npm registry access in different collection via pipeline

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, npm-install

We use Azure DevOps onPremise (Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1).
There we have two collections. "Libraries" and "Projects".

The "Libraries" collection contains a project that hosts an npm artifact feed.
We can run a pipeline in the "Libraries" project and access packages from the feed (e.g. via `npm install`).

Additonally, we have a pipeline in a "Projects" collection project, were we created a "Service Connection" ('iconenpm') to the "Libraries" npm feed using a PAT. (This PAT was created for the pipeline user and is BASE64 encoded).
The PAT is also added to the pipeline user's `%userprofile%\.npmrc` file.

However, we are not able to successfully run an `npm install`.
This is the task:

```
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: 'npm install'
    inputs:
      command: 'install'
      customEndpoint: 'iconenpm'
```

[UI task setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aT3L.png)

and the error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
npm ERR! To correct this please trying logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

...
additonal log output
...

2085 error code E401
2086 error Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.
```

One note: when there is no package from our custom feed in the `package.json`, the pipeline works fine. As soon as we want to access some package via the Service Connection, the pipeline fails.

Does anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you see the error it says to try npm login. But I would recommend **not to try npm login** as it logs you in the `npmjs.com` website or your default registry, not in your Azure DevOps organization.

As given in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#credentials-setup).

> If you are developing on Windows, it is recommended that you use `vsts-npm-auth` to fetch the credentials and inject them into your *%USERPROFILE%.npmrc*. The easiest way to set this up is to install `vsts-npm-auth` globally and then add a run script to your *package.json*.

But if you are developing in any other platform following these steps mention this document to correctly [setup the credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=linux#credentials-setup).

If after setting up the credentials correctly you are facing the same issue then, I would suggest to follow the steps mentioned below to resolve the problem.

1. ##### Check if token is expired

   Maybe the token is expired. Simply navigate to Azure DevOps and generate new credentials and store it in .npmrc file at user level.
2. ##### Refresh the token

   Inside your project, you can open a terminal and run  `vsts-npm-auth -F -C .npmrc`.
   This script refreshes the token.
3. ##### Check if URL contains space

   Check if the URLs in .npmrc file at user level contain space then, **replace every space with %20**.
   I found that when trying to authenticate, if the Artifact Page URL and .npmrc file URLs somehow don't match because of that space then, it throws the 401 error.

I would suggest to read this [troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#troubleshooting) section of Microsoft document and this [How to connect and authenticate to NPM feeds on Azure DevOps](https://www.code4it.dev/blog/connect-npm-feeds-from-azure-devops) document for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Nevertheless, I already checked all of your suggestions.
As I wrote in my question, the problem is surely not an incorrect PAT since I can run an npm install when I run a pipeline living in the same Azure DevOps onPrem Collection.

It does not work when using a ServiceConnection to get access to "Collection A" when the pipeline runs in "Collection B".

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue and I encountered the problems below :

I have a project from Azure DevOps Collection A that have to access to the private NPM feed from Collection B.

In the .npmrc in your repo, you must double check that the registry is correctly named :

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.com
@collectionB:registry=https://mydevopsserver.x.y/collectionB/_packaging/collectionB/npm/registry/
always-auth=true
; auth token below..
```

Something like **%40Local** should not be in the url. **That was my first issue.**

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.com
@collectionB:registry=https://mydevopsserver.x.y/collectionB/_packaging/collectionB%40Local/npm/registry/
always-auth=true
; auth token below..
```

I also found another issue, as I created a demo repo to try to reproduce the error, **I forgot to add package-lock.json which was causing the same issue!**

Finally, I also found a workaround, you could add a custom npm install step by **forcing** a specific .npmrc from the server for example :

```
npm install --userconfig c:\Users\userX\.npmrc
```